# New to Azure Event Grid - trying to react to *any* object being created, deleted or modified

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I'm completely new to Event Grid, but have been tasked with creating a way to track anytime **any** object is created, deleted, or modified within a subscription (additional noise filtering to be added later). Does this sound like I'm on the right track?

Logic App -> Workflow Designer:

When a resource event occurs:
Resource Type - Microsoft.Resources.Subscriptions
Resource Name - (subscription being watched)
Event Type Item - 1
Microsoft.Resources.ResourceDeleteSuccess
Event Type Item - 2
Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess

What I'm completely unclear on is how to output the object deleted/created/modified. Like write to a log or send an email "X" object was deleted by Y user. If anyone has a clue on that, I would greatly appreciate it. Or if there is an easier way to accomplish this, rather than using Event Grid, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WAY-1**

Here is my Logic App flow
[image]

I'm using **Outlook 365 Connector** with `Send an Email` Action
[image]

The **Event Data** gives whole information on What, When and Who created/modified/Deleted the resource.

Here is the screenshot of the mail that I received.
[image]

you can add as many events as possible by clicking Add New Item
[image]

---

**WAY-2**

You can add logs to your storage account and check the details from there as below.
[image]
[image]

---

**WAY-3**

You can check it in the logs from **Overview** pane which gives complete details on particular Run Triggers.
[image]
[image]